# The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 90 seconds elapsed. errors found in ResponderMiddleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient, ocelot

I used Ocelot -v 17.0.1 for load balancer purposes. But currently, I got an exception like this.

**The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 90 seconds elapsed. errors found in ResponderMiddleware.**

I know that Ocelot default timeout is 90s, According to this [link](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/qualityofservice.html).
And I've read some issue that similar with ResponderMiddleware errors, but there is no one same with my case.

Here is my config file :

```
 {
      "Routes": [
        {
          "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{everything}",
          "DownstreamScheme": "http",
          "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
            {
              "Host": "192.xxx.xxx.xxx",
              "Port": xxxxx
            },
            {
              "Host": "192.xxx.xxx.xxx",
              "Port": xxxxx
            },
            {
              "Host": "192.xxx.xxx.xxx",
              "Port": xxxxx
            }
          ],
          "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/{everything}",
          "LoadBalancerOptions": {
            "Type": "LeastConnection"
          },
          "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST" ]
        }
      ],
      "GlobalConfiguration": {
        "RequestIdKey": "OcRequestId",
        "AdministrationPath": "/administration"
      }
    }
```

And here is configuration for HttpClient using IHttpClientFactory

*Startup.cs*

```
services.AddHttpClient("Client", c =>
{
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    c.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
})
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler()
{
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (m, crt, chn, e) => true
});

services.AddScoped<ITypedClient, TypedClient>();
```

*ClientApp*

```
 private ITypedClient _httpClient { get; set; }
    
    public ClientApp(ITypedClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
    
    
    public List<Model> GetEmployee()
    {
        var result = _client.GetReq("/employee");
        
        return result;
    }
```

Is everybody got the same error as me here? What's really going on? Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ocelot is dead. Just use Yarp https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/getting-started.html